# Tomcat 8: Configure connectors in a custom file

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have made some configurations regarding the connectors in Tomcat. The configurations are done in `server.xml`. However, it is not recommended to edit this file directly. So my question is, can I put my configurations elsewhere?  For example, I have a custom `context.xml` where I have put my resource configurations. The settings in this file overrides the default `context.xml`.

Can this be done in the same way, but for the connectors?

Comment: What makes you say that it's not recommended to edit `server.xml` directly?

Comment: According to Tomcat documentation, the context settings for an application should be placed:  

- In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml  
- In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory  
- Inside a Host element in the main conf/server.xml  

It is not recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file.    

But, this recommendation is for context elements. Is it possible to place <Connector> elements in individual files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<Connector>` is not application-specific. It's entirely appropriate to place `<Connector>`s directly in Tomcat's `conf/server.xml` file. That's why the stock server.xml file that ships with Tomcat contains connectors.

To answer the question as originally-phrased, Tomcat doesn't have an obvious mechanism for including "extra" files in `conf/server.xml`, but you can use XML mechanisms to accomplish it.

**I would not recommend this technique because it requires that your server enable external entity processing, which can [decrease the security of your environment](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing).**

It would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Server [
  <!ENTITY extcfg SYSTEM "extra.xml">
]>
<Server port="8005" shutdown=SHUTDOWN">

  ...
  ...

  <Service name="Catalina">
    ...
    ...
    &extcfg; <!-- This will import extra.xml to this location -->
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Then you'd just have this content in your `extra.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8009" ... />
```

Again, I wouldn't recommend this technique, but it should work.

Instead, just put your `<Connector>`s directly into `conf/server.xml`.